# Print into file descriptor using perl s/.../.../e

Tags: perl

I am encountering an error with the following `perl` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open $fh, '>', 'myfile.txt' or die;
s|(.*)|print $fh "Hello",$1," how are you"|e;
close $fh or die
```

> String found where operator expected at ./script.pl line 3, near "$fh "Hello""
>       (Missing operator before "Hello "?)

I use the `s|(.*)|...|e` to write the start of the string another time, like `Hello Hello`.

The expected output the file `myfile.txt` is

> Hello Hello, how are you?

Is there a way to make it run with the actual operations?

Or must I change the `s|(.*)|...|e` operation in another way?

Comment: Why would you use sed, when you can use one of the most powerful tools in Perl - plain simple RegEx and accomplish the same thing very easily.

Comment: Why do you want to write to a file from within the substitution? Perl gets confused about your code, but you can help it by using the "expression syntax" for filehandles: `s|(.*)|print {$fh} "Hello",$1," how are you";|e;`. But the better code would be: `s|(.*)|Hello,$1, how are you|; print $fh $_;`.

Comment: @Corion Thank you for your reply, the better code you provided is a solution !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, what works is to enclose the filehandle in curly brackets:

```
s/(.*)/print {$fh} "Hello",$1," how are you"/e;
```

It's a good practice to use them always, anyway.